# Can not access public struct in swift new package

Tags: ios, swift

I start a new project in swift with a workspace. I add a new package in the project called ApplicationCore by using File - New - Package. After i add the new package i see a a file in the package which is automatically created called ApplicationCore.swift with the following code.

```
//ApplicationCore.swift

public struct ApplicationCore {
    public private(set) var text = "Hello, World!"

    public init() {
    }
}
```

Then i add another folder called Colors and inside this folder i create a new swift file called AppColors.swift. Here is the code...

```
//AppColors.swift

import Foundation

public struct AppColors {
    public let greenColor = Color.green
}
```

So i need to access the struct AppColors from within the struct ApplicationCore which exists in the ApplicationCore.swift file. I use this code inside ApplicationCore

```
public private(set) var AppColorGreen = AppColors.greenColor
```

I get a message saying

Cannot find 'AppColors' in scope

What am i missing? I am new to swift so any help appreciated.

Actual Path: Sources/ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.swift and Sources/Colors/AppColors.swift

Comment: Where do you create the file AppColors.swift, is it in the same folder as the other file?

Comment: To expand on Jaokim's question a bit, it's not clear where these files are in relation to each other.  Maybe give their paths relative to the package.  So for example `Source/ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.swift` and `Source/ApplicationCore/Colors/AppColors.swift`, except whatever your actual paths are.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson As i wrote it is in another folder called Colors. Both ApplicationCore Folder and Colors Folder are under Sources folder. Sources/ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.swift and Sources/Colors/AppColors.swift

Comment: @ChipJarred I updated my question and responded to Joakim

Comment: @stefanosn, move your `Colors` folder inside of the `ApplicationCore` folder, unless you intend for it to be a separate package product, in which case you'd need to edit your `Package.swift` to add it as another product and target.

Comment: Basically, if your package is intended to have a single product (library, for example), which is the most common case, and that library is called `ApplicationCore`, then you want *all* of the source code to be inside of `Source/ApplicationCore`.  You'd use other folders in `Source` if you wanted your package to provide multiple libraries, but that doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: @ChipJarred Thank you it worked. So if i use now in my main project outside of the Package this line ApplicationCore().AppColors.greenColor it should work. I wonder if there is any way to use it like this AppColors.greenColor after importing the ApplicationCore to my swift file outside of the package...without writing all the time ApplicationCore().

Comment: If you make `greenColor` a `static` property rather than an instance property, you could just use `AppColor.greenColor` like you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you've put your `Colors` folder in the wrong place.

For a package that provides a single product (library, executable, etc...), if that product is called `X`, then you want all of the source code for `X` to be inside of `Source/X`.   This is how SPM sets up a package initially.

In your case, you have a package, which I suppose is called `ApplicationCore`, which provides a product/target that is also called `ApplicationCore`.  So all of your source code should go into `Source/ApplicationCore`.

You don't have to use the same name for the product as for the package, but that is the default for the `Package.swift` file SPM creates.  To change it, you'd need to edit the `products` and `targets` arrays in `Package.swift`, and name the directory in `Source` to be whatever name you pick for the product.

Comment: You're welcome.  I glad I was able to help